# Wrong SQL output

Tags: sql

[image]Ok, so I am dealing with 4 tables here - Project, Members, Iterations and ProjectIterationMembers. When I create new project details, I am writing them to the Project table and I am also specifying an iteration (start date, end date - a project consists of at least one iteration, but more iterations can be added afterwards). Members from the Members table are now written to the ProjectIterationMembers table as they are assigned to iterations.

What I am trying to do is display project details in a datagridview in this format:

```
Project Name | Project Manager | Project Status

Project A    | Person A | In Progress
Project B    | Person B | In Progress
```

However, my output is this for some reason when I add a new project or new iterations:

```
Project Name | Project Manager | Project Status

Project A    | Person A | In Progress
Project A    | Person B | In Progress
Project B    | Person A | In Progress
Project B    | Person B | In Progress
```

Here is my sql statement and thanks for your help:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(Project.ProjectName), 
    Project.ProjectID, 
    Project.Status, 
    Project.CompanyID, 
    Project.StartDate, 
    m.MemberID, 
    m.FirstName + ' ' + m.LastName AS ProjectManager
FROM
    Project, 
    Member m, 
    ProjectIterationMember
WHERE
    m.CompanyRole = 'Project Manager'
    AND Project.CompanyID = '" + co_id + "'
    AND m.MemberID = ProjectIterationMember.MemberID
ORDER BY
    Project.StartDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i see from your sql, you are probably missing a join between tables Project and ProjectIterationMember and you get cartesian join.

I can't help you more then this since i have no idea what your ER diagram or at least table definitions look like.

edit: from your ERD, here is how from and where should look like:

```
FROM Project, Member m, ProjectIterationMember, ProjectIterationID pid 
WHERE m.CompanyRole = 'Project Manager'
  AND Project.CompanyID = '" + co_id + "'
  AND m.MemberID = ProjectIterationMember.MemberID
  AND pid.projectIterationID=ProjectIterationMember.ProjectIterationID
  AND pid.ProjectID=Project.ProjectID`
```

Comment: The PK for Project is ProjectID, Then there is a relationship with the Iterations table {ProjectIterationID - PK, ProjectID - FK}, Iterations to ProjectIterationMember {ProjectIterationMemberID - PK, ProjectIterationID - FK, MemberID - FK}, and finally Member has a relationship with ProjectIterationMember {MemberID - PK}

Comment: OK, you need to add this relationship in your sql in where clause and include table ProjectIterationID in from clause. Try this instead your from & where clause

`FROM
    Project, 
    Member m, 
    ProjectIterationMember,
 ProjectIterationID pid
WHERE
    m.CompanyRole = 'Project Manager'
    AND Project.CompanyID = '" + co_id + "'
    AND m.MemberID = ProjectIterationMember.MemberID
 AND pid.projectIterationID=ProjectIterationMember.ProjectIterationID
 AND pid.ProjectID=Project.ProjectID`

Comment: ok, i obviously have problems formatting the code, so i'll edit my answer and add the sql there

Answer (score 0):

If there can be one project manager **per iteration**, you have to expect one row per iteration.

Of course you can group them together by project manager. Or you could remove the project manager altogether.